# Perform division within single column where classes are identical

Tags: r, dplyr

For a dataset I am working on I have repeatedly found myself doing processes manually that I imagine can be done programatically.

Essentially, I want to create a new column where division is performed by using all the values of one column as the numerator but the denominators are a subset of that same column based on a categorical variable.

To do this, I imagine two solutions

1. Create a new column that does the division directly (i.e., divide one value by another where the class is identical)
2. Create a new column of the desired values that can then be used as the denominator (i.e., repeat values where class is identical)

However, I do not know how to do carry out either of these solutions programatically (i.e., using dplyr, plyr, etc.) so currently I am manually creating the necessary columns.

I have built a toy data set to illustrate my desired results:

```
# option 1
df <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16),
                 class = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D"),
                 class2 = c("W","X","Y","Z","W","X","Y","Z","W","X","Y","Z","W","X","Y","Z"),
                 desired.operation = c("1/1","2/2","3/3","4/4", # values of class A divided by values of class A where class2 is identical
                                       "5/1","6/2","7/3","8/4", # values of class B divided by values of class A where class2 is identical
                                       "9/9","10/10","11/11","12/12",# values of class C divided by values of class C where class2 is identical
                                       "13/9","14/10","15/11","16/12")) # values of class D divided by values of class C where class2 is identical

df

# option 2
df2 <- data.frame(value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16),
                 class = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D"),
                 class2 = c("W","X","Y","Z","W","X","Y","Z","W","X","Y","Z","W","X","Y","Z"),
                 desired.newcol = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4, # values for class A repeated where class == A or class = B and where class2 is identical
                                      9,10,11,12,9,10,11,12) # values for class C repeated where class == C or class = D and where class2 is identical
)

df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(desired = value/desired.newcol)

df2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses `data.table::rleid()`

```
library(data.table)

df %>%
  mutate(gp:=class %in% c('A','B')) %>% 
  arrange(class2,class) %>% 
  group_by(id = rleid(class2,gp)) %>% 
  mutate(result=value/value[class %in% c('A','C')]) %>% 
  select(-gp,-id)
```

A data.table only approach would be:

```
setDT(df)[,gp:=class %chin% c('A','B')][
  order(class2,class),result:=value/value[class %chin% c('A','C')],by=.(rleid(class2,gp))][
    ,gp:=NULL][]
```

Output:

```
      id value class class2 desired.operation result
   <int> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>              <dbl>
 1     1     1 A     W      1/1                 1   
 2     1     5 B     W      5/1                 5   
 3     2     9 C     W      9/9                 1   
 4     2    13 D     W      13/9                1.44
 5     3     2 A     X      2/2                 1   
 6     3     6 B     X      6/2                 3   
 7     4    10 C     X      10/10               1   
 8     4    14 D     X      14/10               1.4 
 9     5     3 A     Y      3/3                 1   
10     5     7 B     Y      7/3                 2.33
11     6    11 C     Y      11/11               1   
12     6    15 D     Y      15/11               1.36
13     7     4 A     Z      4/4                 1   
14     7     8 B     Z      8/4                 2   
15     8    12 C     Z      12/12               1   
16     8    16 D     Z      16/12               1.33
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

I did manage to make this work for my real data, but I actually have eight values for 'class' and had to split my data into two data frames of four classes each, apply your method, and then rbind() them back together afterwards. Maybe there's a way to avoid this, but I didn't figure it out.